# How to receive touch event in Qt?

Tags: qt

Is there any way to receive when the screen is touched in Qt. I need to reset a counter to 0, whenever the touch screen is touched.

I'm having the function `systemIdleControl` which resets the counter to zero. So when I touch the touch screen it should call the `systemIdleControl`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your environment and platform is correctly setup then you should receive touch events as mousePressEvent's in a QWidget.
From there you should call your function.

Comment: How can I connect the mousePressEvent to the slot 'systemIdleControl'?

Comment: In the event you can emit a signal that you connect to the slot, or you can directly invoke the method or you can use QMetaObject::invokeMethod according to your other requirements.

Comment: Could you pls explain how can i receive that touch event?

Comment: As reported in the answer, provided the system is correctly setup, touch events are received like mouse clicks are. If you're having specific problems or errors, than ask precise questions.

Comment: I need to call the function 'systemIdleControl', during the touch event happens. Now how can in receive mouse click event or where i need to write function for calling 'systemIdleControl'.

Comment: One possible way is subclassing QWidget to reimplement mousePressEvent. Read the documentation for QWidget: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qwidget.html.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to intercept all touch events, regardless of which widget is touched, one way to do so is to subclass `QApplication` (or `QGuiApplication` if that's your choice) and override its `notify` method.  Something like

```
class TouchResetApplication : public QApplication
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_DISABLE_COPY(TouchResetApplication)
public:
    TouchResetApplication(int&, char**);
protected:
    bool notify(QObject*, QEvent*) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;
};


TouchResetApplication::TouchResetApplication(int& argc, char **argv)
    : QApplication(argc, argv)
{
}

bool TouchResetApplication::notify(QObject *receiver, QEvent *event)
{
    switch (event->type()) {
    case QEvent::TouchBegin:
    case QEvent::TouchUpdate:
    case QEvent::TouchEnd:
    case QEvent::TouchCancel:
        systemIdleControl();
        return true;
    default:
        return QApplication::notify(receiver, event);
    }
}
```

If you want the touch events to be processed as normal after calling `systemIdleControl`, then you can of course remove the `return true` and let it fall through to the default.

An alternative is to install an event filter on `QCoreApplication::instance` instead.  A full list of your options is described in the documentation of `QCoreApplication::notify`.